# Access denied for user from a remote host

Tags: networking, server, mysql

I'm trying to connect with MySQL Database, but I'm getting *"Access denied from user 'remoteuser'@'cmapc.iserver.local'"*. Let me show you all the scenario:

I have a server Ubuntu 14.04 with hostname 'icma', MySQL 5.6 and Bind9 to configure a local DNS Server. The server points to itself domain 'iserver.local' and each machine has a subdomain configured at Bind9 DNS: [machine-name].iserver.local which in the networking connections receives the DNS sufix as 'iserver.local' and it points the primary DNS to my local server. The machines:

(Ubuntu Server) icma.iserver.local. (192.168.1.125)
(Windows 10) cmapc.iserver.local. (192.168.1.100)
(Windows 10) jeapc.iserver.local. (192.168.1.101)

At this point, is everything working well, all machines are communicating to each other and all services such as: FTP, SSH, are working well. The firewall is configurated to enable all necessary ports. But, there's a problem.

I can't connect to MySQL from CMAPC machine (with host cmapc.iserver.local or with its IP 192.168.1.100). I always getting "Access denied from user 'remoteuser'@'cmapc.iserver.local'".

I've tried:

```
CREATE USER 'remoteuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '**********';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'remoteuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It not worked, so I've tried:

```
CREATE USER 'remoteuser'@'cmapc.iserver.local' IDENTIFIED BY '**********';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'remoteuser'@'cmapc.iserver.local' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

It not worked, so I've tried:

```
CREATE USER 'remoteuser'@'192.168.1.100' IDENTIFIED BY '**********';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'remoteuser'@'192.168.1.100' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And I don't know what's going wrong...

**Info 1**

The file my.cnf has the line # bind-address=127.0.0.1 commented.

**Info 2**

The problem with connection is in Windows 10 of CMAPC machine while connecting to Ubuntu Server.

I've tried to connect with another machine in the same network and also with Windows 10 (jeapc.iserver.local) and I got success!

But when I tried, again, to connect with (cmapc.iserver.local) Windows 10 machine... I got "Access denied from user 'remoteuser'@'cmapc.iserver.local'".

I don't know how I can fix it...and I don't know if the problem is in Windows 10 or Ubuntu Server.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663001/remote-connections-mysql-ubuntu

Comment: @bodhi.zazen have you read my question? I related I did this procedures...

Comment: It is hard to know from what little you posted, thus the link. Could be anything from wrong password to firewall on windows for all we know.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen the ubuntu server looks working good, all configurations were done and everything is fine. The stranger thing is: when I try to connect with user 'remoteuser' from jeapc.iserver.local (Windows 10), then MySQL connection is done. But when I try to connect with the same user and password from cmapc.iserver.local (Windows 10), then MySQL connection is not allowed. 'remoteuser' has a wildcard and localhost sign in database users. Works well in all devices just doesn't work in cmapc.iserver.local and I have no idea why... any ideia?